# Is my circuit to power 38 kHz LED matrix correct?

Tags: mosfet, led-matrix, powermosfet

I'd like to send 38kHz signals to an LED matrix to pulse 5V IR LEDs. The intention is that a lot of IR will be reflected when a finger is placed on a translucent 3mm acrylic panel above the LEDs. The reflected rays will be read by a TV IR sensor.

I'd like to check if the circuit I've designed for pulsing the LEDs is correct. On the right is a [16-channel mux](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4067.pdf) connected to an ESP32 on the input. The output is fed to 11 [power MOSFETs](http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF9540N_-100V_-23A_117mO_Vth-4.0_TO-220.pdf), which in turn are connected to 11 rows of LEDs that the MCU will switch on 1 row at a time.

In particular:

- Is the mosfet section of the schematic correct? (what can I read to understand how to design these?)
- How do I choose a value for the resistor next to the MOSFETs?
- Do I need a capacitor somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Realistically you should re-design this with N-FETs as low side switches.  If you expect to turn on more than one row, you should give each *individual* LED its own resistor, otherwise brightness will vary depend on the number of LED's activated.  It's not however very clear why you aren't building a big series-parallel array with a single FET to blink it all in unison.  The TV receiver won't care... Or are you trying to do some sort of spatial imaging?   Most IR receivers don't give any strength output, though a few do crudely.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking the question. Let's discuss step by step,

**1. Is the MOSFET section of the schematic correct? (what can I read to understand how to design these?)**

No, it's not. You have to connect Mosfet Source to 5V directly and You have to use a gate discharge resistor(10K) between Mosfet Gate and Mosfet Source. Use Gate resistance of 100Ω for switching at 38KHz.

**2. How do I choose a value for the resistor next to the MOSFETs?**

It totally depends upon how much current your gate driver can provide and how fast you want to switch MOSFET. In your case *ON STATE RESISTANCE* of Mux us around 100 ohms and ESP32 can provide at max 40mA@3.3V, so you can use any resistance between 82.5Ω to a higher value. 100Ω will give you a decent switching speed.

**3. Do I need a capacitor somewhere?**

Yes, You have to use a 1uF ceramic disc decoupling capacitor between Vcc and Vee of your Mux and You have to use 100uF Capacitor between 5V and Ground near to LED Matrix.